# Pass Parameters through ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to pass parameters through the following:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod));
```

Any idea how to do this? I'd appreciate some help

Comment: use thread.Start(paramValue) to begin.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

lazyberezovsky has the right answer.  I want to note that technically you can pass an arbitrary number of arguments using lambda expression due to variable capture:

```
var thread = new Thread(
       () => DoMethod(a, b, c));
thread.Start();
```

This is a handy way of calling methods that don't fit the `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate, but be careful that you can easily cause a data race if you change the arguments in the parent thread after passing them to the child thread's code.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why is a data race more likely using this method than it is with the ParameterizedThreadStart or ThreadStart method?

Comment: @2-bits: Because when using this method the variables are captured by reference, so any change in the parent thread will affect the value inside the child thread as well. Also, the variables are captured when the lamda actually executes, as opposed to when the thread starts, which gives a small window for data races to occur if the values are modified in the parent.

Comment: so you have a closure here?

Comment: it's not answer to the question, there are situation you don't want to use lambda

Answer (score 39):

Use overloaded [`Thread.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc.aspx) method, which accepts object (you can pass your custom type or array if you need several parameters):

```
Foo parameter = // get parameter value
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod));
thread.Start(parameter);
```

And in `DoMethod` simply cast argument to your parameter type:

```
private void DoMethod(object obj)
{
    Foo parameter = (Foo)obj;
    // ...    
}
```

**BTW** in .NET 4.0 and above you can use tasks (also be careful with race conditions):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoMethod(a, b, c));
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a class to pass in multiple parameters as @user1958681 has done, you could use anonymous types, then just use the dynamic typing to extract your parameters.

```
class MainClass
{
    int A = 1;
    string B = "Test";

    Thread ActionThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork));    
    ActionThread.Start(new { A, B});
}
```

Then in DoWork

```
private static void DoWork(object parameters)
{
   dynamic d = parameters;

    int a = d.A;
    string b = d.B;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to archive what you want, is by returning a delegate within your function / method. Take the following example:

```
class App
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     Thread t = new Thread(DoWork(a, b));
     t.Start();
     if (t.IsAlive)
     {
         t.IsBackground = true;
     }
  }

  private static ThreadStart DoWork(int a, int b)
  {
      return () => { /*DoWork*/ var c = a + b; };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(() => { DoMethod(a, b, c); }).Start();
```

or

```
new Thread(() => DoMethod(a, b, c)).Start();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to differ from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parameters to pass to ParameterizedThreadStart delegate
// - in this example, it's an Int32 and a String:
class MyParams
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MyParams(int someInt, string someString)
    {
        A = someInt;
        B = someString;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    MyParams ap = new MyParams(10, "Hello!");
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod));
    t.Start(ap); // Pass parameters when starting the thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program 
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    ParameterizedThreadStart pts = myClass.DoMethod;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(pts);
    thread1.Start(20); // Pass the parameter
    
    Console.Read();
  }
}

class MyClass 
{
  private int Countdown { get; set; }

  public void DoMethod(object countdown) // Parameter must be an object and method must be void
  {
    Countdown = (int) countdown; 
    for (int i = Countdown; i > 0; i--) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
  }
}
```