# Passing parameter between thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have a regular multithread which process a parameter/value

```
  public void testThread (int fib)
  {
    int a = 1;
    int fib2 = fib + a;
    Console.WriteLine(" Thread : "+fib);
  }
```

how can i pass the result value back to MainThread or another Thread ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776846/pass-parameters-through-parameterizedthreadstart

Comment: Threads don't have results, and while you can devise mechanisms to pass data back and forth, `Task` is a much more natural fit.

Comment: @Piotr That's a *really* bad solution to the problem.

Comment: fib? Recursive multithreaded fibonacci - because recursion and multithreading don't cause enough bugs by themselves already.

Answer (score 0):

You usually pass data between threads by writing the data into some shared data structure, like a queue that one thread is writing to and another thread is reading from.

There are other explicit ways, however.  For example, if you are trying to get data from a background thread to the UI thread, so you can invoke UI API's with that data, then there are techniques to execute bits of code on other thread contexts.

For example, you can use the Task class from System.Threading.Tasks to start a task on the UI thread if you know the TaskScheduler associated with the UI thread. You can get that from TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() when your code is executing on the UI thread, and save it in a static variable to use later.